# Find the number closest to and greater than an input number in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have written this short code that gives me the closest number to a number I receive from a dictionary.

```
def find_closest_timestamp(departs: dict, timestamp: int):
    bus_id, closest_time = min(departs.items(), key=lambda x: abs(timestamp - x[1]))
    return int(bus_id), closest_time
```

how can I make use of this  line but at the same time check if the closest time is bigger then the timestamp I receive because I don't need the closest from below the number only from above.

thanks for the helpers.

Comment: You could try: `key=lambda x: (abs(timestamp - x[1]), -x[1])`.

Comment: it still returns the closest number.  and i need the closest number that is greater then timestamp. even if the differential between them is lower. f.e : dict that contains  1 2 3  5 (the keys not matter) and the number i receive is 4  i need to return 5 and not 3.

Comment: Then filter before finding the min: `min(((k, v) for k, v in departs.items() if v >= timestamp), key=lambda x: x[1] - timestamp)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from math import inf

def find_closest_timestamp(departs: dict, timestamp: int):
    bus_id, closest_time = min(departs.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1] - timestamp) if timestamp <= x[1] else inf)
    return int(bus_id), closest_time

departs = {1: 5, 2: 9, 3: 10, 4:0}
print(find_closest_timestamp(departs, 6))
```

If the dictionary values are greater than or equal to `timestamp` then we are returning the dictionary values minus `timestamp` from the lambda function. If a dictionary value is not greater than `timestamp`, we are returning `inf` which is greater than any number in the list. The minimum of these is our expected result.

Comment: thanks ! that works. although its a bit difficult to understand. xD

Comment: @KellyBundy please explain what's wrong with the code.

Comment: I am sorry for the first code, I never checked for corner cases. Thanks to @KellyBundy for correcting me.

Comment: Actually I'd say you *only* checked a corner case :-P

Comment: Could also use infinity. Though in the real world, proper filtering and handling the "there aren't any" case might be best.

Comment: Yeah, I never thought of using inf, I was searching for a C equivalent of MAX_INT. Thanks again, I learnt a lot from answering without much considerations. :D